# check the user input type using python and streamlit

Tags: python, if-statement, streamlit

I want to check the user input if its numeric or string.

The problem is that the if statement always take the user input as string even if the input is numeric its converted by default into a string.

How to fix this problem ?

```
all_columns = df.columns.tolist()
st_input_update = st.number_input if is_numeric_dtype(all_columns) else st.text_input
with col1_search:
    regular_search_term=st_input_update("Enter Search Term")
```

Comment: Have you tried `int(st_input_update("Enter Search Term"))`?

Comment: `df.columns.tolist()` returns a list, yes? So, why should `is_numeric_dtype` be true for a list? Maybe you want to check if all elements of the list are numeric?

Comment: i think my logic was wrong because what i want is to check the user input if its numeric or string

Comment: Then you can use `st.text_input` and try-except a ValueError like the answer below shows.

Comment: @OneCricketeer i tried it did not work

Comment: The edit your question to show what you tried and what errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `is_numeric_dtype()` should either be a type or a pandas array. You gave it a list of column names, which is neither.

Use `df.dtypes` to get an array of datatypes.

```
st_input_update = st.number_input if is_numeric_dtype(df.dtypes) else st.text_input
```

Answer (score -1):

```
user_input = input("Enter something:")
try:
    x = int(user_input)
    print("Is a number")
except ValueError:
    print("That's not an int!")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `type(int(user_input)) == int` will always be true.

Comment: Did you read the question, or just the title? It's about testing whether the type of all the data in `all_columns` is `int`, not the user input.

Comment: @Barmar i want to check if the user input is int or not not all the data  sorry for the misleading